# Rate Limit DNS Subdomain Requests

Tags: dns, enumeration, cloudflare

I work at a company that provides a SaaS program for other organizations, and each subscribed organization receives their own subdomain of their choosing - generally they choose the organization name. We recently discovered that there are tools that can use brute force DNS requests to enumerate the subdomains for a given domain. Our company would like to prevent this if possible, as someone could 'build' a list of our clients by doing so.  I'm wondering if there is a way to 'rate-limit' DNS requests, in order to prevent this - we use Cloudflare as our DNS provider, and they do offer rate -limiting for http requests, but I haven't seen anything about DNS request, so I'm wondering if this is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: What you want is not possible due to the way DNS works.

DNS does not work like HTTP where some client accesses a server and where this specific client can be rate-limited by this server. Instead DNS is a distributed directory service, consisting of many *authoritative* name servers which provide information about "their" domains and additional *recursive* name servers which collect and cache such information for their clients.

A request to resolve a specific domain will typically not come directly from the client but from another *recursive* name server which was asked by the client to resolve this domain. This means that there is no direct relationship between a DNS request received by the *authoritative* name server the and a client: the same client might use different *recursive* name servers so that the source of the request at the authoritative name server differs. And many client will usually use the same *recursive* name server so that any rate limiting will affect many clients and not only the specific client one likes to slow down.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, that answered my question!